# Stargazer drops first regressor if first model is univariate plm, but not if first model is multivariate plm

Tags: r, stargazer, plm

I use the `stargazer` package to make LaTeX tables of panel models (`plm` package). If the first `plm` model is univariate, then `stargazer` drops that model's regressors, but still displays the model.

If I swap the model order so that the first model is multivariate then all models display. I don't have this problem with `lm` models. Is there a work around? Does it matter that `lm` includes an intercept while `plm` does not?

Thanks! Here's an example.

```
dat <- data.frame(y=runif(1000),
                  x1=runif(1000),
                  x2=runif(1000),
                  id=rep(1:50, each=20),
                  time=rep(1:20, times=50)
                  )
pdat <- pdata.frame(dat, index=c("id", "time"))
plms <- list()
plms[[1]] <- plm(y ~ x1, data=pdat)
plms[[2]] <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=pdat)
plms[[3]] <- plm(y ~ x2, data=pdat)

# drops first regressor if first model is univariate
stargazer(plms[1:3], type="text")

# but not if first model is multivariate
stargazer(plms[c(2, 1, 3)], type="text")
```

This yields the following.

```
> # drops first regressor if first model is univariate
> stargazer(plms[1:3], type="text")

========================================================================
                                 Dependent variable:                    
             -----------------------------------------------------------
                                          y                             
                     (1)                 (2)                 (3)        
------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1                                      0.004                           
                                       (0.032)                          

x2                                     -0.008              -0.008       
                                       (0.032)             (0.032)      

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations        1,000               1,000               1,000       
R2                 0.00002             0.0001              0.0001       
Adjusted R2        0.00002             0.0001              0.0001       
F Statistic  0.016 (df = 1; 949) 0.038 (df = 2; 948) 0.059 (df = 1; 949)
========================================================================
Note:                                        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01

> # but not if first model is multivariate
> stargazer(plms[c(2, 1, 3)], type="text")

========================================================================
                                 Dependent variable:                    
             -----------------------------------------------------------
                                          y                             
                     (1)                 (2)                 (3)        
------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1                  0.004               0.004                           
                   (0.032)             (0.032)                          

x2                 -0.008                                  -0.008       
                   (0.032)                                 (0.032)      

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations        1,000               1,000               1,000       
R2                 0.0001              0.00002             0.0001       
Adjusted R2        0.0001              0.00002             0.0001       
F Statistic  0.038 (df = 2; 948) 0.016 (df = 1; 949) 0.059 (df = 1; 949)
========================================================================
Note:                                        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in the latest release of `stargazer` (version 5.0), now available on CRAN.

Comment: Snap. Thanks for stargazer!